# Check if a number is in a range with zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh, arithmetic

Why is passing 0 as an argument results in a false positive (prints "True")?

```
#!/bin/zsh

k="$1"

if ((0 < k < 1))
then
    echo "True"
fi
```

Note this script is called stitch_applier.sh

Terminal

```
% ./stitch_applier.sh 0
True
```

This was run on a Linux system.

Comment: very few languages support chained comparison like that: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shell's arithmetic doesn't support chained comparisons like that. Instead, the first `a < b` returns either `1` or `0`, depending on if the relation is true or not.

So, if `k` is `0`, then `((0 < k < 1))` is `((0 < 0 < 1))`, the same as `(( (0 < 0) < 1))` because of left-association. Zero is not less than zero, so `0 < 0` is falsy, so in an arithmetic context, `0`. Then we have `0 < 1`, which is truthy, and there you go.

If you want to test if `k` is within a range, you need to do `((0 < k && k < 1))`.

Note that e.g. Bash and many other shells only handle integer arithmetic, and there are no integers that fit strictly between zero and one, so in those shells, the test will always fail. Ksh and Zsh can deal with floats, though.

---

That's the way the operators [work in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison), and all of [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04), [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) and [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html) refer to the C definitions of the arithmetic operators. (POSIX defines only `$(( ))`, not `(( ))`, but Bash and Zsh treat arithmetic identically in both. Doing otherwise would be confusing.)

Some newer languages work differently. Python, being famously friendly,  [supports chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), and [Rust](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/python-like-chained-comparison-operators/13191) and [C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0893r0.html) have at least discussed adding similar support. Like that C++ document comments, no-one ever uses `a < b < c` on purpose in the C sense anyway. (Something like `(a < b) != (c < d)` may have uses, though. It checks if exactly one of the relations is true.) Perl and GNU awk seem to give a syntax error for `1 < 2 < 3`.

Comment: Yea Ive been spoilt by python.. Also I swapped the script to zsh for the reason you mentioned at the end...